# Google One-tap project status

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

Does anyone know what is the status of Google One-tap AKA YOLO project?

It seems like all the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web) on One-tap is gone. The cached version states:

> The beta test program for this API is currently closed. We are improving the API's cross-browser functionality and will provide updates here in the coming months.

There are quite some websites which are still using this technology, either because they were in Beta and/or whitelisted by Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a new version that addresses the feedback and issues from the beta, it's available as of 2020 Q1: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web

Comment: Steven should we expect any development on this in 2020?

Comment: New version was released recently: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web

Comment: Thanks Steven for the update, I just integrated it in my app. I was wondering if there is any way to customize the styles of prompt? For example I would like to remove the rounded corners of the prompt to make it similar to other elements of my site which uses material theme.

Answer (score 2):

All of the prior URLs regarding one tap are all 404 errors now.  Seems like it was totally canned and they are deferring to the more generic sign in integration from a website login page.

Comment: I've seen it implemented on Medium and Zillow but I too cant get it to work

Answer (score 1):

The [offical document](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web) of the project has been updated. Please see the latest status there.

Answer (score 0):

this time stuff gonna be the opposite > 2. Headings:

> reword//06{GUIDEDLATEVIEW||2022 blank